# SQL Server full-text search for Latex content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, latex

I have a web app that allows users to save Latex content to a SQL Server 2012 database. I am running a full-text query as below to search for Latex expression.

```
SELECT MessageID, Message FROM Messages m  WHERE CONTAINS (m.Message, N'2x-4=0');
```

The problem I am facing with above query is that some of the messages being returned by above query do not contain the latex expression `2x-4=0`. For example, a message whose saved value is as below is also being returned by above query. You can clearly see that there is no 2x-4=0 contained in this message.

```
<p>Another example of inline Latex is \$x=34\$.</p>
<p>What are the roots of following equation: \$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0\$?</p>
```

**Question**

Why is this happening and is there a way to get correct records returned when doing a full text search to look for  the latex expression `2x-4 = 0`? I have tried to repopulate the full text search data for the table being used, but it had no effect.

**UPDATE 1**

Strange, but the following Latex expression filter always returns exact matching results. I am now looking for `$2x-4=0$` rather than `2x-4=0`.

```
SELECT MessageID, Message FROM Messages m  WHERE CONTAINS (m.Message, N'$2x-4=0$');
```

I have two types of delimiters for latex expression in my app: `$$` for paragraph display and `\$` for inline display of Latex expression, and therefore there will always be a $ symbol surrounding the latex expression stored in database, though the trailing delimiter could be `\$` but full-text search seems to ignore the backslash character.

Why this modified query returns exact matches is not clear to me.

**UPDATE 2**

Another approach that works accurately is as mentioned in the answer. The full query for this is mentioned below. So, the LIKE operator ends up scanning only those rows that are selected by full-text search query.

```
WITH x AS
  (SELECT MessageID,
          Message
   FROM Messages m
   WHERE CONTAINS (m.Message,
                   N'2x-4=0') )
SELECT MessageID,
       Message
FROM x
WHERE x.Message LIKE "%2x-4=0%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTAINS` is more like an end-user search operation, with support for keywords like `NEAR`, `AND` and `OR`. Try adding quotes within the quotes, to force the exact search term:

```
SELECT MessageID, Message FROM Messages m WHERE CONTAINS (m.Message, N'"2x-4=0"');
```

This is called `<simple-term>` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql).

You can also try the [`LIKE` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql):

```
SELECT MessageID, Message FROM Messages m WHERE m.Message LIKE '%2x-4=0%';
```

But note that this is probably slower than `CONTAINS` because it doesn't use a full text search index. If it's too slow, maybe you can even combine both of them in one query, so the `CONTAINS` is used to filter the result set down to the non-noise words using the index, and then `LIKE` applies the final matching.

Comment: I tried it that way with this query, but still getting the same results. `SELECT MessageID,Message FROM Messages m WHERE CONTAINS(m.Message, N'"2x-4=0"')`

Comment: So, you are suggesting something like a CTE which uses the full-text search query and then adding another query that acts on this CTE using a LIKE operator?

Answer (score 2):

To understand why it happens you can run the following query (`1033` is the English language id):

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('2x-4=0', 1033, 0,1)
```

In my instance it would return the following results:

[image]

Note, all other parts of the search criteria are considered to be noise words except for `2x`. Therefore, I suspect your full text index simply does not have the full `2x-4=0` string and instead you get results with occurrences of `2x`.

I tried adding `2x-4=0` to my own FTS index and `CONTAINS` was able to find it as the top result for both `CONTAINS(col, '2x-4=0')` and `CONTAINS(col, '"2x-4=0"')`. However, partial matches were included too right after the exact match.

Note, that when extra white space is added around `=` in the search term the FTS parser won't accept it and complain about syntax error.

Comment: "and `CONTAINS` was able to find it": the issue was with `CONTAINS` finding too much, not too little.

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to stress that adding " around the search term would not cut off unmatched results. Instead it would list the exact match on top and the other partial matches underneath.

Comment: @andrews, Thanks for the answer. Normally users of my app would save Latex content very often and in such a situation would it be possible to enforce the FTS index that you mentioned on full Latex expressions?

Comment: @Sunil, Latex expressions contain a lot of format characters. SQLServer FTS may have trouble properly understanding these expressions as a single term. You can examine `select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords where language_id=1033` to see what other stop words are defined in the system and see if there are too many Latex control characters. Honestly, I like the solution proposed by Thomas, try narrowing your search results with `CONTAINS` and then get the exact match with `LIKE` out of the initial FTS search result.

Comment: @andrews, Yes, it seems that is the only solution when searching for Latex expressions. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas, I tried using AND with CONTAINS, but it gave me an empty result set. I used: `SELECT MessageID,Message FROM Messages m WHERE CONTAINS(m.Message, N'2x-4 AND =0');`

Comment: @Sunil when using `AND` you need to make it like this: N'"2x-4" AND "=0"' but are you sure it will help?

Comment: @andrews, I tried this query but still get an empty result set: `SELECT MessageID,Message FROM Messages m WHERE CONTAINS(m.Message, N'"2x" AND "-4" AND "=" AND "0"');`

Comment: @Sunil, I think it's the wrong way. Try concentrating on CTE with `CONTAINS` and further `LIKE`. In your original query do you get at least one exact match for `2x-4=0`?

Comment: @andrews, I get no records returned by my query when I use AND in the query posted in my last comment.

Comment: @Sunil but does this original query `SELECT MessageID, Message FROM Messages m  WHERE CONTAINS (m.Message, N'2x-4=0');` return you at least 1 result with the exact `2x-4=0` occurrence?

Comment: @andrews,  It returns 4 records,  out of which 2 are perfect matches for the expression 2x-4=0.  The other two have no such expression in them.

Comment: @Sunil OK, good. Then you just need to cut off those 2 extra not-fully-matching records using `LIKE` applied to CTE. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @andrews,  that is not a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @andrews,  is there some system defined function that tells if it's  a perfect match or not when using full text search?

Comment: @Sunil, there is a system level FTS Rank value assigned to each returned result. But it is available only with [CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql). The exact matches will get the highest Rank.